# Regex TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from a web page. I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 and regexes.

The problem is that it returns an error but I can't figure out why the error is raised.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
urls = soup.findall('a',href = re.compile(r'/katalog/stavebnictvi/'+'.'))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Web_Crawlers\idatabaze_cz.py", line 14, in <module>
    get_categories_urls()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Web_Crawlers\idatabaze_cz.py", line 10, in get_categories_urls
    urls = soup.findall('a',href = re.compile(r'/katalog/stavebnictvi/'+'.'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

There is at least one tag meeting the condition. 
For example: `<a href="/katalog/stavebnictvi/semily/">`

I think that there is a problem with my regex. I want to search for each tag a where the href is in this form: `/katalog/stavebnictvi/(any text)`

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with `soup.findall`, it must be `soup.findAll` or `soup.find_all`

```
urls = soup.findAll('a',href = re.compile(r'/katalog/stavebnictvi/'+'.'))
```

Comment: Thank you. It's weird that LiClipse doesn't recognised that 'findall' does not exists.